# Is there anyway to change current Activity's intent flag in android? Like making it available in Stack History or Not

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Assume that I have 4 Activities (A,B,C,D)

AppStart -> A -> B -> C -> D

I have a situation that i need to remove C  if something invalidates the necessity of C.

(something invalidates: "For example", C shows details of a product and if user buys that product in C, it will show D (You have bought it!) and when user hits back button, user should not see the product page)

So, the desired scenario:

AppStart -> A -> B -> C -> Something invalidates necessity of C and starts D -> C will have newly gained FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY flag and it will start D.

So, just after starting D, C will be removed:

Stack will be A -> B -> D and whenever user hits "back", user will return to B instead of C.

To summarize, i need to start an Activity without FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY flag but update it with that flag according to actions in that activity.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you simply use "finish()" on C when you start D?

Comment: use "clear top "when call activity d from c

Comment: @Waza_Be can i safely start another activity from current activity after calling finish() on current activity?

Comment: @vsk won't that also remove B?

Comment: Yes, you can do that very simply.. As you accepted Alexei answer, I guess that it works for you ;-)

Comment: @Waza_Be Yes, i was going to accept your answer as you were the first one but i was waiting for your reply. So 2points for you (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling finish() in started activity will remove it from stack. Use it when starting another activity(immediately after StartActivity) or even when activity under consideration is in background. Watch out for leaks in the latter case though